# jQuery - Appending a Div inside Element

Tags: jquery, append

I have a click event that uses `$.ajax` to call the server for some updated html (from my database).

I then place that html inside a specific `div`, using the `.append()` method, thus keeping what's already inside.

So far, it works as expected.
My dilemma is with each newly appended html.  And to clarify, my html is nothing more than a div with a link and a hidden span.  I use the link to `toggle()` the hidden span, and it's contents.
The Toggle isn't working, because the click event isn't listening to the newly appended html.

I'm sure it's something easy to remedy, but I haven't needed to delve into this until now.

So, here's the page 1 Code:

```
<div id="latestinfo">

  <div class="info">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="openinfo">View This</a>
    <span style="display:none">Latest story on something</span>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="openinfo">View This</a>
    <span style="display:none">Latest story on something</span>
  </div>

</div>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="grabmoreinfo">Call Server for More</a>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".openinfo").click(function(){  
   $(this).next('span').toggle();
  });


  $("#grabmoreinfo").click(function(){  
    $.ajax({ 
            url: "latest.php",
            data:"formId=grabmore",
            success:function(data){  $("#latestinfo").append(data); }      
    }); 
  });

});
</script>
```

Now latest.php:

```
<?php

$var = '
<div class="info">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="openinfo">View This</a>
    <span style="display:none">Another story on something</span>
  </div>
';

echo $var;

?>
```

So, in recap, the `append()` works like a charm, while the `click()` method doesn't notice the newly appended html.

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `event delegation`, you are appending contents from other page and it was not available at the time of `page load` so you have to delegate the event to the static parent with `.on()` handler (which existed at the time of page load like `$(document)` or `$('body')` or `$('#latestinfo')`), so i suggest you to do this:

```
$("#latestinfo").on('click', '.openinfo', function(){  
   $(this).next('span').toggle();
});
```

or you can delegate the event to the `$(document)` which is the parent of all elems:

```
$(document).on('click', '.openinfo', function(){  
   $(this).next('span').toggle();
});
```

---

#### Side Note:

**Remember**: Delegated events do not work for SVG.

Answer (score 0):

use `on` delegated event for dynamically generated elements...

```
  $("#latestinfo").on('click',".openinfo",function(){  
   $(this).next('span').toggle();
  });
```

to read more about [on()](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html)

calling click function inside the success function of ajax also works but i prefer to go with  `on` delegated event .

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "on" when attaching event handlers to content that isn't in the DOM yet when the handler is defined

Standard "CLICK" assumes that the elements already exist in the DOM

```
$("#latestinfo").on("click",".openinfo",function(){  
   $(this).next('span').toggle();
  });
```

Looks like you can use latestinfo as "parent"

Answer (score -1):

If you are using older version of jQuery where `.live()` still works you can quickly make your code running by changing your code to the below

```
$(".openinfo").live('click',function(){  
   $(this).next('span').toggle();
});
```

However if you are using newer jQuery version like `1.9.1` i'd recommend you to use `.on()` method as many of the other answers have suggested for binding events on elements which are appended after the page has loaded.

*Note: I recommended `.on()` as it will make your code future proof but `.live()` can be your temporary workaround. Also note that `.live()` is a deprecated in newer jQuery releases.*

Comment: There's no reason to even mention `.live()` because before it was removed completely it was just a shortcut to `$(document).on()`. Unless the OP says that they are using a version that's more than 1.5 years old and can't update it, talking about `.live()` is just pointless and potentially confusing.

Comment: OP didn't mention which version of jQuery he is using thus live is just as possible as on.  And on was introduced in jquery 1.7 so you can't ignore it :) also i've mentioned that `on()` is recommended... Anyways :)